# Rails routing issue - URL works, though button to link to it won't

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, rails-routing

I'm writing what is currently a very inelegant program to generate fitness plans, and have an issue with the routing. I want buttons on my index page linking to certain bodyparts and a plan generator, and the pages themselves are working when I navigate to them directly. However, the buttons on my index view won't work, kicking out a routing error: 'No route matches [POST] "/exercises/index"'.

For example, dropping the URL for '/exercises/legs' or '/exercises/generator' into my browser loads the page as it should be, though <%= button_to "Legs", 'exercises/legs' %> (as well as redirecting to exercises_legs_path and every other option I've thought of) gives the error.

Sure this is something pretty straightforward I'm missing (very new to this), and any advice would be great!

The database currently contains columns for the :id, ':move' (i.e. press up) and ':bodypart' (i.e. legs).

Here are my routes:

```
Helper                      HTTP Verb   Path                            Controller#Action
                            GET        /exercises/:bodypart(.:format)   exercises#bodypart
exercises_generator_path    GET        /exercises/generator(.:format)   exercises#generator
exercises_index_path        GET        /exercises/index(.:format)       exercises#index
root_path                   GET        /                                exercises#index
exercises_path              GET        /exercises(.:format)             exercises#index
                            POST       /exercises(.:format)             exercises#create
new_exercise_path           GET        /exercises/new(.:format)         exercises#new
edit_exercise_path          GET        /exercises/:id/edit(.:format)    exercises#edit
exercise_path               GET        /exercises/:id(.:format)         exercises#show
                            PATCH      /exercises/:id(.:format)         exercises#update
                            PUT        /exercises/:id(.:format)         exercises#update
                            DELETE     /exercises/:id(.:format)         exercises#destroy
```

And my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/exercises/:bodypart', to: 'exercises#bodypart'
  get '/exercises/generator', to: 'exercises#generator' 
  get 'exercises/index'

  root :to => 'exercises#index'
  resources :exercises

end
```

Thanks in advance, and let me know if there's anything else I've got that would help with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/exercises/:bodypart', to: 'exercises#bodypart', as: 'exercises_bodypart'
  get '/exercises/generator', to: 'exercises#generator' 
  get 'exercises/index'

  root :to => 'exercises#index'
  resources :exercises

end
```

instead of

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/exercises/:bodypart', to: 'exercises#bodypart'
  get '/exercises/generator', to: 'exercises#generator' 
  get 'exercises/index'

  root :to => 'exercises#index'
  resources :exercises

end
```

Usage:

```
exercises_bodypart_path('legs')
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmet KAPIKIRAN. Done, though strangely it's giving three different errors for the links I've tested this on.  I've tested on three body parts, 'full', 'shoulders' and 'legs' and am getting the following errors, respectively: full "exercises/full Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/exercises/full"" (as I was initially getting for all of them), for shoulders "exercises/index, Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/exercises/index""  and for legs: "/exercises, NoMethodError in ExercisesController#create
undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass".... any ideas?